# A way to pass more than one datasource/set? to RDLC report as business object

Tags: reporting-services

I have to create one simple report for a small gig I got. I've never used RDLC in my life nor any other type of reporting so this is frustrating me to hell. From what I've read I can pass business objects to my reports to populate them. I have a business object with nested properties in which some are class instances. Accessing them is no problem as I can pretty much drag the class as a field then edit the expression to something like `value.Name`. The problem is that my Collections in my business object do not show up in the Report Data Explorer.

In adding new datasets from objects I can see that my original Business Object is listed 3 times like so

1. MainWindowViewModel
2. MainWindowViewModel(WorkOrderParts) --> which is one of my collections
3. MainWindowViewModel(WorkOrderServices) --> which is my other collection

What I basically did was then add two more data sets pointing to #2 and #3 above in the Report Data explorer and tied those to two tables respectively. They will be displaying a collection of objects representing a part or service done on a work order.

[image]

I know I can pass my BO to my report with this line of code
`this.MainWindowViewModelBindingSource.DataSource = myVM;`

**So my question is:** Is there a way to assign multiple data sources and apply them to data sets made in my Report Data explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question by listing the way data sets work.

- One data source can have none, one or many data sets
- Each data set is stand alone can can't be joined to another
- Each table on the report can only have one data set as the source
- If you require multiple data sets in a table, you have to...
- - join the data before it reaches the report
- - Perform manual lookup in a calculation for each field
- - Alternatively you can have multiple tables or sub reports